# Como saber si una variable contiene una lista?

Tags: python-3.x, arraylist, pycharm

Me surge una duda sobre las lista y esta es, hay alguna forma de saber si una variable es una lista, ya sea una lista vacía y no.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En principio debes usar la función builtin [`isinstance`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/functions.html#isinstance):

> ```
> >>> foo = []
> >>> bar = "Hola"
>
> >>> isinstance(foo, list)
> True
> >>> isinstance(bar, list)
> False
> ```

El primer argumento es una referencia al objeto, tu variable, el segundo la clase/tipo que quieres comprobar. Puedes pasar también como segundo argumento una tupla con varias clases/tipos si quieres comprobar si el objeto es un objeto de alguna de ellas:

> ```
> >>> a = 4
> >>> b = 2.3
> >>> c = "Hola"
>
> >>> isinstance(a, (int, float))
> True
> >>> isinstance(b, (int, float))
> True
> >>> isinstance(c, (int, float))
> False
> ```

A diferencia de `type`, tiene en cuenta la herencia, de forma que te devolverá `True` también para objetos de clases que deriven de `list`. Por norma general, en validaciones, se suele querer tener en cuenta la herencia. Si por alguna razón quieres saber si la variable apunta aun objeto `list` y no a una clase derivada de `list`, entonces usa [`type`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/functions.html#type) con un solo argumento:

> ```
> >>> type(foo) is list
> True
> ```

pero suelen ser casos muy concretos y por norma general no es lo apropiado.

Ten en cuenta que realmente una variable no contiene una lista, ni es una lista, estrictamente hablando, una variable es un nombre asociado a una referencia a un objeto en memoria.

Comment: esto no lo acabo de entender: Puedes pasar como segundo argumento una tupla con varias clases o tipos si quieres comprobar si el objeto es un objeto de alguna de ellas.

Comment: Hola javic, he agregado un ejemplo a la respuesta, espero que quede más claro. Ésto es especialmente útil en la validación de argumentos por ejemplo.

Comment: Con el ejemplo a quedado clarísimo, gracias

Answer (score 0):

podrías probar con:

```
if type(variable) == List():
    #lo que sea que tengas que hacer (si entró es porque es una lista)
```

Saludos.

Comment: no sirve salta un error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'List' is not defined

Comment: perdon que tonto, seria type(List()) en vez de List()

Answer (score 0):

el `list` tiene que estar sin paréntesis `()`, pues sino Python cree que es una función.
Es de la siguiente manera:  `if type(variable) == list: ...`